# Group by day and ID, and sum

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset that I would like to group by the Day, while also summing based on the ID

df:

```
ID                     Duration            Date

A                      5                  9/9/2019 5:46:29 PM
A                      6                  9/9/2019 5:48:00 PM
A                      6                  9/9/2019 6:00:05 PM
B                      2                  9/10/2019 1:00:01 PM
B                      2                  9/10/2019 1:30:00 PM
```

Desired output:

```
ID               Date             Duration

A                9/9/2019         17
B                9/10/2019        4
```

Dput:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), Duration = c(5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L), Date = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("9/10/2020 1:00:01 AM", "9/10/2020 1:30:00 AM", 
"9/9/2019 5:46:29 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:00 AM", "9/9/2019 6:00:05 AM"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

This is what I have tried:

```
df %>%
group_by(Date = as.Date(mdy_hms(Date))) %>% 
summarise(Duration = sum(Duration))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you add `ID` in `group_by` it gives what you want. `group_by(ID, Date = as.Date(mdy_hms(Date))) %>% `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment if you include `ID` in the `group_by` command it gives what you need.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(ID, Date = as.Date(lubridate::mdy_hms(Date))) %>% 
    summarise(Duration = sum(Duration))
```

You can also do this in base R :

```
aggregate(Duration~ID + Date, transform(df, 
      Date = as.Date(as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", 
                                tz = "UTC"))), sum)

#  ID       Date Duration
#1  A 2019-09-09       17
#2  B 2020-09-10        4
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost got it, just add the ID to the grouping fun:

```
df%>%
  group_by(ID,Date = as.Date(mdy_hms(Date))) %>% 
  summarise(Duration = sum(Duration))


#out
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
#  ID    Date       Duration
#  <fct> <date>        <int>
#1 A     2019-09-09       17
#2 B     2020-09-10        4
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(df)[, .(Duration = sum(Duration)), by =  .(ID, as.Date(mdy_hms(Date)))]
```